# Dart Removing disallowed attribute after editor upgraded

Tags: dart, dart-html

I have encounter error "Removing disallowed attribute" after I upgraded my dart editor in SDK 0.7.3.1_r27487.

I have a custom tag which template contains boostarp attributes "data-target" and "data-toggle". It work under previous version but encounter error after upgraded.

Console

```
Removing disallowed attribute <A data-toggle="dropdown">
Removing disallowed attribute <BUTTON data-target=".navbar-collapse">
Removing disallowed attribute <BUTTON data-toggle="collapse">
```

.html Code

```dart
<element extends="div" name="x-navbar" constructor="Navbar">
<template>    
  ..
  <a name="top" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Shop <b class="caret"></b></a>
  ..
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"></button>
</template>
<script type="application/dart" src="custom_ui.dart"></script> 
</element>
```

Comment: Roger, does the code still execute as intended? I occasionally also see such messages (and have even before the latest Editor release), but my Polymer app continues to work fine.

Answer (score 10):

You're probably using [Element.innerHtml](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html#innerHtml=). You should use [Element.setInnerHtml](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html#setInnerHtml) instead.

As you can see with the parameters of this new method, the HTML code is now validated and filtered. To restore the old behavior, you must provide a validator or a tree sanitizer allowing all attributes.

To explicitly allow "data" on anchors and buttons:

```dart
// Call NodeValidatorBuilder.allowX() methods to customize the validator.

final NodeValidatorBuilder _htmlValidator=new NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
  ..allowElement('a', attributes: ['data-target', 'data-toggle'])
  ..allowElement('button', attributes: ['data-target', 'data-toggle']);

query('#anElement').setInnerHtml('a content', validator: _htmlValidator);
```

`Element` and `CustomElement` classes use HTML sanitization in several places (`Element.html` factory, `innerHtml` property, `createFragment` method...).

Even if you don't use these methods directly in your own code, they're called by the underlying Dart libraries (`CustomElement` class was created for `Polymer` library but is also used by latest releases of `Web UI` library).

For the moment, there is NO way to globally disable or customize the default sanitization rules. So I guess you'll have to deal with `setInnerHtml` calls... or wait for another SDK release to fix the issue ("data-" attributes are valid HTML5 code, but the default sanitization filter doesn't allow them as well as inline styles: why these attributes are considered insecure?).

Note: you should consider [switching from Web UI to Polymer](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/upgrading-to-polymer-from-web-ui.html), as [Web UI is now deprecated](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/).

Comment: CedX, thanks for your response but I haven't use Element.innerHtml. I placed all codes within <element><template> in .html. Should I replace all waring parts by using Element.setInnerHtml?

Answer (score 4):

For those who are working with angular dart, you will have to reimplement the NgDirective with custom validations like so:

```dart
library ng_bind_html_unsafe;

import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgDirective(
    selector: '[ng-bind-html-unsafe]',
    map: const {'ng-bind-html-unsafe': '=>value'}    )
class NgBindHtmlUnsafeDirective{
  final dom.Element element;

  NgBindHtmlUnsafeDirective(this.element);

  set value(value) => element.setInnerHtml(value == null ? '' : value.toString(),
                                             validator: new dom.NodeValidatorBuilder()
                                             ..allowHtml5()
                                             ..allowElement('a', attributes: ['href'])
                                             ..allowElement('img', attributes: ['src']));
}
```

In that specific example, I am allowing links and pictures without any sanitization you can extend this however you'd like.

Comment: It cannot find `NgDirective` class. Where is it located?

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 0.9.9 `ng-bind-html` supports custom NodeValidators.

Just register a factory that returns a customized `NodeValidator` like shown in the other answers

```dart
factory(NodeValidator, (Injector inj) => getNodeValidator());
```

and `ng-bind-html` will use this NodeValidator.

I found that the HTML included this way isn't processed by Angular (any directives/components/expressions are ignored).

When I need this I use a custom bind-html directive like shown by @mabounassif with this additional code in the `value` setter after `element.setInnerHtml`

```dart
if(value != null) {
  _compiler(_element.childNodes, _directiveMap)(_injector, _element.childNodes);
}
```

see also https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/742

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use `img` element with `innerHtml` and found that the above answers were incomplete. It was missing the `uriPolicy` that defaults to the same origin. Defining a custom UriPolicy fixed the issue for me.

```dart
class DefaultUriPolicy implements UriPolicy {
  DefaultUriPolicy();

  bool allowsUri(String uri) {
    // Return true/false based on uri comparison
    return true;
  }
}
```

Define validator like below:

```dart
allowElement('img',
              attributes: ['src'], uriPolicy: new DefaultUriPolicy()))
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who wants to use `setInnerHtml` and wants to allow all tags and attributes, you can use this validator:

```
class AllowAll implements NodeValidator {
    @override
    bool allowsAttribute(Element element, String attributeName, String value) {
       return true;
    }

    @override
    bool allowsElement(Element element) {
      return true;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
element.setInnerHtml(
    value,
    validator: AllowAll()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking [@mabounassif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352539/mabounassif)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867266/dart-removing-disallowed-attribute-after-editor-upgraded#22440484) I did the following to also allow links to another sites:

```
import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Directive(selector: '[html-inseguro]')
class HtmlInseguro {
  final dom.Element element;

  final dom.NodeValidatorBuilder _validador;

  HtmlInseguro(this.element)
      : _validador = dom.NodeValidatorBuilder()
          ..allowHtml5()
          ..allowElement('a', attributes: ['href'], uriPolicy: _TodoUriPolicy())
          ..allowElement('img',
              attributes: ['src'], uriPolicy: _TodoUriPolicy());

  @Input('html-inseguro')
  set htmlInseguro(String value) {
    element.setInnerHtml(value?.toString() ?? '', validator: _validador);
  }
}

class _TodoUriPolicy implements dom.UriPolicy {
  @override
  bool allowsUri(String uri) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then in the component you should have sth like this:

```
@Component(
  template: '''
<div class="vista-previa-mensaje" [html-inseguro]="mensajeAEnviar | dataReplacer: reemplazos | md2html"></div>
''',
  directives: [
    HtmlInseguro,
  ],
  pipes: [Md2Html, DataReplacer])
class YourComponent{
  //...
```